# React import App.css as global css file in another file in different location

Tags: reactjs

I want to import the App.css as a global CSS file in another js file that is in a different location.

my js is located in
`src/components/folderA`
and the App.css file is located in the src folder.

I did import `"../../App.css"` in my fileA.js file
also added import `"./App.css"` in my App.js file.
Also I tried these two codes in my App.css file but it doesn't work.

```
 :global(body) {
  background-color: #black;
}


(body) {
  background-color: #black;
}
```

How can I import the App.css file?

Comment: Why would you want global CSS values in a component other than your primary application component? What are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: In my project folder, js files have each CSS file and there are some tags for sharing the same styling for the title, body, etc. I want to make a global file for more efficiency than every time add the same styling in each CSS file :)

Comment: I would make those global rules something that you publish with your page (e.g. it's included in the template's header, and stored in the folder with your html template). From there you can ensure they're always included/present in your page, so the derivative CSS pages can operate off them. Alternatively there's more robust solutions with Less/SASS